# access object property name as string

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-material-table

I have an array of string, that I am trying to convert to an array of objects, on order to dynamically create a mat table, using the guide on the [Angular Material Website](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/app/table-generated-columns-example.ts) example from Angular Material, but they're not really doing it dynamically, as their columns are manually typed in the component

```
columnsToDisplay: string[] = [
                                'log_id',
                                'computer_id',
                                'processor_test',
                                'display_test',
                                'storage_test',
                                'network_test',
                                'keyboard_test',
                                'mouse_test',
                                'userfields',
                                'hard_disk_id',
                                'start_time',
                                'hard_disk_serial',
                                'gigabytes',
                                'target_drive_detailed',
                                'drive_detailed',
                                'target_drive',
                                'pattern_name',
                                'wipe_status',
                                'errors',
                                'dirty_sectors',
                                'tool',
                                'kernel',
                                'job_uuid',
                                'uuid',
                                'end_time',
                                'end_time_short',
                                'num_passes',
                                'trim_passes',
                                'sectors_overwritten',
                                'sectors_not_overwritten',
                                'sectors_verified',
                                'custom_field_legacy',
                                'nis_method_type',
                                'dco_foundremoved',
                                'dco_locked',
                                'hpa_foundremoved',
                                'amax_foundremoved',
                                'vendor',
                                'chassis',
                                'computer_model',
                                'computer_serial',
                                'computer_summary',
                                'motherboard_summary',
                                'cpu_summary',
                                'nic_summary',
                                'display_summary',
                                'usb_ports',
                                'computer_memory',
                                'hard_disk_drive_media_type',
                                'hard_disk_product',
                                'hard_disk_vendor',
                                ];
```

```
this.columnsToDisplay.forEach((field: string) => {
      const selected: boolean = this.displayedColumns.some((column: string) => column === field);
      this.columnSelection.push({
        value: field,
        viewValue: field.toUpperCase().replace('_', ' '),
        selected: selected,
        cell: (element: ErasureModel) => `${element.[field]}
      })
    });
```

Obviously it is the element.[field] that is not working

Is it at all possible to generate this, so that for the field log_id I could have it say element.log_id?

Comment: `element[field]` (no dot). see: [Property accessors: bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)